# How to avoid nesting of "node_module" directory?

Tags: node.js

In some cases, that comes into conflict with the Windows 260 chr path limitation. I'm having a lot of problems with npm install and this limitation.

```
.
├── app
│   └── node_modules
│       └── submodule
│           └── node_modules
│               └── submodule
│                   └── node_modules
│                       └── submodule
│                           └── node_modules
│                               └── submodule
│                                   └── to_infinity_and_beyond... 
│                                       └── It's a madness!
```

**...**

That structure produces paths like:

c:/path_to_my_app/
node_modules/sub_module/node_modules/sub_module/node_modules/sub_module/node_modules/sub_module/node_modules/sub_module/node_modules/sub_module/node_modules/sub_module/node_modules/sub_module/node_modules/sub_module/node_modules/sub_module/.....

What i'm doing wrong? It's there a way to avoid it?

Perhaps renaming "node_module" to "nm", or something like that, may helps to save some characters...

That's in advance!

Comment: Does this help at all? https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2966

Comment: [`npm dedupe`](https://npmjs.org/doc/dedupe.html) should help.

Comment: npm dedupe works fine for me, but only with submodules with same version number. On the other hand, makes sense... Thanks!

Comment: Alfonsomartinde, would you mind closing the question if the solution brought by Jonathan was sufficient ? thank you !

Comment: You're right! But I don't know how to do that :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As  Brandon Tilley said:

```
npm dedupe
```

works fine for me!